# finding data with multiple conditions and replacing it with new data

Tags: microsoft-excel, find

I am working with 2 worksheets, 1 contains all my raw data and the other works as a dashboard with my pivot table and charts.

I hope you can help me create a cell input range in my dashboard worksheet that finds a cell in the other worksheet based on multiple conditions and replace it with the new value.

Somewhat trying to vlookup a data and replacing it with a new one.

thanks

Comment: No, you can't modify a piece of data without.. modifying *that* piece of data. At least not with a formula. You could do it with VBA. You could also use `replace` but you'd have to have the new data in a new cell rather than the old.

Comment: Hi Raystafarian,  can I ask for your help with the vba that would do this.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with [this](http://superuser.com/questions/700930/excel-vba-code-private-sub-worksheet-change-power-function-not-working/701027#701027) and see how much you can do and come back if you get stuck